# How to get uitextview height for collectionviewcell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to build collectionview with textview inside collectionviewcell.I want to calculate height of cell based on textview.

I use **sizeThatFits** method to calculate the height but as the text grow bigger, the height of collectionviewcell does not match with text.

I tried to use **boundingRect** but the result was also incorrect

[image: result picture]

Is their anyway to calculate correct height of textview? or how to solve this problem.

Thank you!!

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let textview = UITextView()

    textview.text = statusText[indexPath.row]

    let actualsize = textview.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: actualsize.height)

}
```

Comment: Did you try `boundingRectWithSize ` ??

Comment: Yeh, I tried boundingRect  as I said above.The result is still not correct

Answer (score 3):

By default, when you create a new instance of `UITextView` the font attribute is `nil`, you must associate a font to UITextView before use `sizeThatFit`.

If you are using the default font, just add `textview.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)`

Change your function like this :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let textview = UITextView()

    textview.text = statusText[indexPath.row]
    textview.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

    let actualsize = textview.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: actualsize.height)

}
```